# AADSTS50001 error on Web API with Azure AD

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I have created a new web api and deployed it on azure. The api works with azure AD authentication. This api we need to consume from PowerBI-Desktop application.

If i test the api on browser which is deployed on azure it works fine. However, if I try to consume it in PowerBI it gives the following error.

> invalid_resource: AADSTS50001: The application named  was not found in the tenant named . This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Why I am getting this error ?

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Based on the error massage, it should caused by invalid resource uri. What resource uri did you used? `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api`?

Comment: This article may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/get-azuread-access-token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log in as an admin and make a GET request like so:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=[APPLICATION ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]

And then you'll authorize the application and you'll be able to authenticate =)